Properties of greedily-defined sequence $(a_n)$: any relation to primes? Asymptotically is $a_n\sim n\log n?$ analysis? Anything in the literature?
Let $p_n$ be the $n-$th prime.
Consider the greedy algorithm-defined sequence: the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n=1$ and $a_{n+1}$ is the least next(-greatest) integer (than $a_n$) such that for each $k\geq 2,\ \{a_j\pmod k:1\leq j\leq n+1\} \neq [k]:=\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}.$ This gives rise to the sequence:
$$ a_1=1,\ a_2=3,\ a_3=7,\ a_4=9\ a_5=13,\ a_6=19,\ a_7=21,\ a_8=27,\ a_9=31,\ a_{10}=33,$$
$$ a_{11}=37,\ a_{12}=43,\ a_{13}=49,\ a_{14}= 51,\ldots $$
I noticed, by comparing the gaps of this sequence with the prime gaps, that it seems reasonable to hypothesise that,
$$a_n+10=p_{n+4}\quad \forall\ n\geq 1.$$
Is this connection true, and if so, why? Is this remarkable or not? [Almost certainly not...]
I feel like this is related to prime sieving, although I fail to put my finger on the connection.
I do see that $a_{15}$ will be the next least integer greater than $51$ that is not:

$\equiv 0 \pmod 2$
$\equiv 2 \pmod 3$
$\equiv 0 \pmod 5$
$\equiv 4 \pmod 7$
$\equiv \{2,5,8\} \pmod 9$
$\equiv 6 \pmod {11}$
$\equiv 2 \pmod {13}$

and indeed, this is $57\ (=p_{19}-10=67-10),$ as expected.

EDIT (and answer to the original question:) $a_{16}\neq 61$ because if
$a_{16} = 61$ then $\{a_{j}\pmod {11}:1\leq j\leq 16\} =
 [11]:=\{0,1,\ldots,10\}.$ So the pattern fails to follow the prime
numbers. (In fact, $a_{16}=63.$)



New question:
Is anything known about this sequence $a_n?$ (in relation to prime
numbers?) Is there anything related in the literature? Is $a_n\sim n\log n?$


I don't understand the condition in your definition of $a_{n+1}$, it seems to be imposing a constraint on the earlier $a_j$.

@Rob I think my definition is correct. It is not imposing a constraint on the earlier $a_j.$ The previous numbers in the sequence have already been decided. Rather, it is helping you decide what the next number in the sequence can be. For example, say we have $a_1=1, a_2=3, a_3=7, a_4=9.$ Then $a_{n+1}=a_5$ cannot $=10,$ for then we would have ${a_j\pmod 2:1\leq j\leq 5} = [2]={0,1}.$ We cannot have $a_5=12$ for the same reason. We cannot have $a_5 = 11,$ for then ${a_j\pmod 3:1\leq j\leq 5} = [3]={0,1,2}.$ But we can have $a_5=13$ as there are no violations, and so we let $a_5=13.$

See OEIS entry A172407 for "Positive numbers $n$ such that $n+10$ is a prime".

@StevenClark Please can you advise how that is helpful?

Here's the correct sequence on OEIS:
https://oeis.org/A020498

Does it not answer your question "Is this connection true"?

@RaviFernando Note OEIS entries A020498 and A172407 reference each other under sequence in context.

@Steven Clark Well I already disproved the connection with a counter-example when I updated my question.

Hmmm... why is A020498 the same as my sequence? A020498 is "a(n) is the least number > a(n-1) such that a(1) through a(n) do not contain all residues modulo any prime." My sequence is "a(n) is the least number > a(n-1) such that a(1) through a(n) do not contain all residues modulo any integer." So why are they the same?

Are your sequence and A020498 not subsets of A172407? I suspect this is why A020498  and A172407 cross reference each other.

I have no idea. I'm not yet convinced my sequence is A020498, although it does have a similar flavour due to the similar definitions. Also I'm not sure if a sequence appearing in "sequence in context" implies that it a subsequence.

Sorry, I haven't got around to seriously investigating your question. If your conjecture is true, your sequence would have to be a subset of $A172407$, but you're right $A020498$ is not a subset of $A172407$ since for example $111\in A020498$ but $111\notin A172407$. In your definition of the sequence $(a_n)$, should $a_n=1$ really be $a_1=1$?

With respect to your question" why is A020498 the same as my sequence?", how can the sequence generate all of the residues modulo a composite number if it doesn't generate all of the residues of any of its factors? Are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem which relates the residues of a composite number to the residues of its factors?

I coded up the algorithm for your sequence in Mathematica and your sequence $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, ... , a_{58}\}$ exactly matches A020498 for which there are cases where $a_n+10\notin\mathbb{P}$ as well as cases where $a_n+10\in\mathbb{P}$ but $a_n+10\ne p_{n+4}$ as illustrated in the following table. Note that $a_n+10\in\mathbb{P}$ seems to occur far more often than $a_n+10\in\mathbb{P}\land a_n+10=p_{n+4}$, so perhaps this less restrictive condition is worth more investigation.
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 n & a_n & a_n+10 & p_{n+4} & a_n+10\in\mathbb{P} & a_n+10=p_{n+4} \\
 1 & 1 & 11 & 11 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 2 & 3 & 13 & 13 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 3 & 7 & 17 & 17 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 4 & 9 & 19 & 19 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 5 & 13 & 23 & 23 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 6 & 19 & 29 & 29 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 7 & 21 & 31 & 31 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 8 & 27 & 37 & 37 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 9 & 31 & 41 & 41 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 10 & 33 & 43 & 43 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 11 & 37 & 47 & 47 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 12 & 43 & 53 & 53 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 13 & 49 & 59 & 59 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 14 & 51 & 61 & 61 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 15 & 57 & 67 & 67 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 16 & 63 & 73 & 71 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 17 & 69 & 79 & 73 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 18 & 73 & 83 & 79 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 19 & 79 & 89 & 83 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 20 & 87 & 97 & 89 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 21 & 91 & 101 & 97 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 22 & 97 & 107 & 101 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 23 & 99 & 109 & 103 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 24 & 103 & 113 & 107 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 25 & 111 & 121 & 109 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 26 & 117 & 127 & 113 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 27 & 121 & 131 & 127 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 28 & 129 & 139 & 131 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 29 & 133 & 143 & 137 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 30 & 139 & 149 & 139 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 31 & 141 & 151 & 149 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 32 & 147 & 157 & 151 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 33 & 153 & 163 & 157 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 34 & 157 & 167 & 163 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 35 & 159 & 169 & 167 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 36 & 163 & 173 & 173 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 37 & 169 & 179 & 179 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 38 & 177 & 187 & 181 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 39 & 183 & 193 & 191 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 40 & 187 & 197 & 193 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 41 & 189 & 199 & 197 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 42 & 199 & 209 & 199 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 43 & 201 & 211 & 211 & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 44 & 211 & 221 & 223 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 45 & 213 & 223 & 227 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 46 & 217 & 227 & 229 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 47 & 231 & 241 & 233 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 48 & 241 & 251 & 239 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 49 & 243 & 253 & 241 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 50 & 247 & 257 & 251 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 51 & 253 & 263 & 257 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 52 & 261 & 271 & 263 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 53 & 267 & 277 & 269 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 54 & 271 & 281 & 271 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 55 & 273 & 283 & 277 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 56 & 279 & 289 & 281 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
 57 & 283 & 293 & 283 & \text{True} & \text{False} \\
 58 & 289 & 299 & 293 & \text{False} & \text{False} \\
\end{array}$$

It looks like the "reason" why $a_n + 10$ is often prime is simply that it's never divisible by $2$, $3$, $5$, or $7$; that is, $-10$ is the last excluded residue modulo each of these primes.  This isn't true for the next primes $p = 11, \dots, 67$ because $p-10$ is in the sequence.

@RaviFernando I suspect you're right about that, but is it obvious why $\gcd(a_n+10,2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7)=1$ is always true?

By definition, once all but one of the residue classes modulo $p$ are occupied (and this happens very quickly for $p = 2, 3, 5, 7$), the sequence will avoid the last one forever.

@RaviFernando Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. For example in line 25 in the table $a_{25}+10=121=11\cdot 11$, but wasn't all but one of the residue class modulo $11$ occupied much earlier? In fact, I believe $a_{1171}+10=9911=11\cdot 17\cdot 53$.

Yes it was.  My point is this:  the first six terms $a_1, \dots, a_6$ are congruent to $1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 5$ modulo $7$.  This means (by plugging in $k=7$ to the definition) that there will never be an $a_n$ which is congruent to $-10 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$.  Repeating this modulo $11$:  the first terms $a_n$ are congruent to $1, 3, 7, 9, 2, 8, 10, 5, 9, 0, 4 \pmod{11}$, so at that point $6$ is the only missing residue, and is therefore forbidden from that point onwards.
